# how to insert a custom(run time) value in a form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

i have 2 tables in Microsoft Access

1)SALES   containing columns

product  and product price

2)STOCK   containing columns

product ,price and quantity

i have created a form against the table SALES

i want that when i enter the product name in the product column it automatically gets the price from the STOCKS table against the product i have entered.

i may have to enter like 10 products name and the add the price of each to get the TOTAL SALE value  ( i am making a Point Of Sale system )

how can this be achieve

thanks

Comment: How about uploading a small database in which we can see what you've done? So what do we know about the form you have created "against" table SALES?

Comment: Just want to clarify one thing for now: Why does the SALES table contain the Price column? Does it mean that the price at which a product is sold can be different from the price recorded for the product in the STOCK table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `productField` an `priceField` are fields in your form, you have to add this code to the `on exit` event of `productField`

```vb
If Not prodChanged Then exit sub ' if the user hasn't edited the product
Dim recSet As Recordset
Set recSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select stock.price from stock where stock.product =" & Me.productField.Value)
If Not recSet.EOF Then 'If the product exists
    Me.priceField = recSet.Fields(0)
Else
    'do default action
End If
podChanged=false 'reset the product editted state
```

you have to declare the global boolean variable `prodChanged` initialized to `false` and set it `true` in the `OnChange` of `productField`

Comment: I wouldn't use the exit event, it would mean that tabbing though the form would update sales, probably against the user's requirements. In addition, the question does not refer to forms, but to tables and unless a product sold can have a different price, as per the comments, the whole thing is against the rules of normalization. I would also ask where a form is getting the product data? A combo seems to be the best bet, and if this is sensibly based on the inventory, the price can be a hidden column in the combo, ...

Comment: ... which means that the price can easily be written to a textbox by referencing that column. Your answer seems to be using control and field interchangeably, unless I have misunderstood.

Comment: the question is not pretty clear, but he want to get price value from the stock table. I edited the code to do that